# How to debug relay-starter-kit ? (database.js, schema.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, relayjs

The relay-starter-kit uses babel-node to run the ES6 style JavaScript.

I would like to debug the server side code like database.js and schema.js.

I tried node.js remote debugging but wasn't able to stop in any of my break-points. I also tried different ways of enabling debugging like `babel-node --debug ./server.js`. But nothing worked so far. I guess somehow I have to tell babel to generate debuggable output with source-maps or so?

To be more exact, how can I debug `getUser` in `database.js` for example?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

## Insert a debugger statement

```js
mutateAndGetPayload: ({id, text}) => {
  debugger;
  /* ... */
},
```

## Run the server with the debugger engaged

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node debug ./server.js
< Debugger listening on port 5858
debug> . ok
break in node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:1
> 1 "use strict";
  2 
  3 // istanbul ignore next
debug> c
< GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:8080
< Relay TodoMVC is now running on http://localhost:3000
break in data/schema.js:278
 276     var text = _ref11.text;
 277 
>278     debugger;
 279     var localTodoId = (0, _graphqlRelay.fromGlobalId)(id).id;
 280     (0, _database.renameTodo)(localTodoId, text);
debug>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug with sourcemap support. Does anyone know?